# E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages

Tags: apt

I have ubuntu 20.04
When I try run command `sudo apt-get upgrade` I have got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.6.ubuntu.bionic.custom) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6.ubuntu.bionic.custom is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6.ubuntu.bionic.custom is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6.ubuntu.bionic.custom is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try run command `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I have got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.6.ubuntu.bionic.custom) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6.ubuntu.bionic.custom is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6.ubuntu.bionic.custom is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6.ubuntu.bionic.custom is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I can't install any package !